# Get formatted file content from Bitbucket API

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-api

Is there some way to get Bitbucket formatted file content instead raw text using Bitbucket API? I'm using cURL in PHP.

Comment: By formatted, what do you mean?

Comment: @Randommm I mean to not get it as raw text. To keep newlines, text indent, etc.

Comment: They are shown as is on the browser, are you sure your fetching function just doesnt get rid of them?